# php youtube json decode

Tags: php, json

I tried to use JSON decode to get the youtube API feed. However, when I paste the JSON result in `http://www.jsonlint.com/` I noticed something like

```
"media$group": {
  "media$category": [
```

Unfortunately some symbols are rejected by php. Here is my code, I tried to remove this `$` symbol, but maybe not success. How do I solve this?

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videosq=football&orderby=published&v=2&alt=json';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$body1 = curl_exec($ch);
$body = str_replace('$','', $body1);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($body);
foreach ($data->feed->entry as $result) { 
...
}
```

Comment: `json_decode` is not affected by `$` in the strings. You realize the shown URL gives an `Invalid request URI` error?

Comment: @mario, I want to get the mediadescription. if I ignore `$`, use `echo $result->mediagroup->mediadescription;` it called back `Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is the usage of PHP identifiers to access the contents. The simplest solution here would be to get an array instead of an object:

```
$data = json_decode ( $json , $assoc = true );
```

This allows access to fields with:

```
echo $result['media$group']['media$description'];
```

If you want to keep the object syntax, that's possible with this kludge:

```
echo $result->{'media$group'}->{'media$category'};
```

(But arrays are safer here. You don't get a fatal error should the format change and properties be absent.)

Answer (score 0):

This work:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football&orderby=published&v=2&alt=json';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$body1 = curl_exec($ch);
$body = str_replace('$','', $body1);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($body);

foreach ($data->feed->entry as $result) { 
    var_dump($result);
}
?>
```